# Supplementing Iodine separately from antioxidants? (and separately from what else?)

Tags: supplement, antioxidant, iodine

What should NOT be taken with Iodine? I've heard that it's a strong oxidant, so taking it with Vitamin C (and I assume other antioxidants) is a bad idea.

Comment: Personal medical advice is off topic here, so I edited your question to make it generic and applicable to everyone.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you, I seem to phrase a question wrongly 9/10 times on Stackexchange, so I am very glad when someone edits it before people close it down. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking a product that contains both iodi**n**e and iodi**d**e like Lugol's or Iodoral, the only thing that happens when you add an antioxidant like Vit C is that the iodine gets converted to iodide. This is not a bad thing. But people like Dr. Flechas point to research showing that while the thyroid utilizes iodide, other organs, tissues, and glands utilize iodine, or a combination of both -dide and -dine. So it defeats the purpose of taking in "dual form" which the products mentioned above are in. Standard advice for taking iodine, if you don't want it converted to iodide, is to take it at least a 1/2 hour before Vit C or other antioxidants; one hour to be safe.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: More succinctly, just a link or two supporting your main claims would be sufficient.